# How can I tell what gates I have access to after each mission?

Tags: freelancer

Freelancer restricts gate access until after certain story line missions.  How can I tell what systems I have access to after each mission without attempting to fly through them all?  Is there a resource that lists the accessible gates after each plot mission?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After the second story mission, you can jump to any system in Liberty (except Alaska).
This includes jump holes.  (note that if you take the jump hole to California after landing on Manhattan for mission 3, you will miss an interesting video and a unique and powerful gun)

After the fourth story mission, all gates are unlocked.  (except story-only gates like Tohoku)

However, if you fly across border worlds (and into a higher region), you will find it very difficult to survive.
In other words, you can go from Kusari to Bretonia during the story, but if you fly from either of those to Rhineland, the enemies will be too strong.

Comment: nice, that's handy.  I love the challenge of getting into places where I'm not supposed to be... like Omicron alpha

Comment: @spartacus: You can't; equipment has a minimum level requirement in  single-player.

Comment: yea, I forgot that mines had requirements too, I thought it was just for guns.

Comment: I once tried flying to Rhineland from Bretonia, and got slaughtered by hostile Bounty Hunters in Hammerheads.

Comment: I've already swapped ships so BHs are on longer aggressive.  Its the corsairs I have to worry about.  Hoping to do most of my flying on 'kill engine and go backwards' mode to make them not chase.

Comment: Good luck... Especially in the asteroid field in Tau 23 & 37.

Comment: 10 years later and I'm still learning about freelancer, I've never heard about that gun before, awesome!

Comment: @spartacus do you know what that gun is called? I'm interested.

Comment: @kotekzot: It has two different names; one in the scanner (before tractoring it) and one in the equipment list.  To get it, shoot the neutral ships that appear after jumping into California after landing on Manhattan.  Beware that loading from the jump autosave will miss the opportunity (save on West Point first).  Beware their Moonstalker missiles.

Comment: @SLaks can you tell me what those names are?

Comment: @kotekzot: `Nomad Prototype` and `Rowlett's Revenge`, respectively.

Comment: @kotekzot yea, Rowlett's Revenge is the name